# O que são migrações do modelo de banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, mvc

Alguns frameworks MVC (Rails, Laravel e outros) disponibilizam migrações do modelo de banco de dados. O que são, como funcionam e quais as vantagens / desvantagens de utilizá-las?

Answer (score 2):

Migração é o procedimento que altera o estado de um banco de dados.

> Assim como código fonte, a estrutura de um banco de dados altera à medida que desenvolvemos uma aplicação atrelada a esse banco. Por exemplo, ao longo do desenvolvimento, podemos querer adicionar uma nova tabela; ou após uma rotina de deploy, notamos que será necessário adicionar um novo índice ou coluna. É importante que acompanhemos essas mudanças estruturais no banco de dados (chamadas de migrações) como fazemos com o código fonte. Se o código fonte e o banco de dados estão fora de sincronia, é muito provável que o sistema como um todo comece a ter problemas.

(traduzido de http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/pt/database.migration)

Resumindo: suponhamos que sua aplicação tenha sido modelada para um estado A de um banco de dados, e após a inserção de um determinado novo recurso, o banco de dados teve de ter ser alterado para um estado B. Essa alteração ocorreu por meio de uma migração, que em geral são um conjunto de *queries* que adicionam colunas, tabelas, índices e dados no banco de dados, de forma que o mesmo esteja no formato requerido pela aplicação.

Answer (score 2):

> Quais as vantagens / desvantagens de utilizá-las?

Basicamente, você ganha um controle maior dos estados do banco em diferentes momentos. Também pode ser usado em conjunto com um sistema de controle de versão, como o Git, para que possam ser executados facilmente por outros programadores, para terem o estado atual do banco.

Fazendo as alterações "na mão", via SQL, outros usuários não vão conseguir reproduzir as alterações em suas máquinas, a menos que saibam exatamente o que foi alterado.

Assim como os ORMs, os Migrations também geram a sintaxe correta do SQL dependendo do banco.